# Is there any way to get a Dell service tag through dell.com website?

Tags: laptop, website, warranty

I purchased a Dell computer through dell.com in August 2009. It qualifies for the Windows Vista to Windows 7 free upgrade. I don't have the laptop on hand (it was a gift), though I copied down the service tag which is required to schedule an upgrade. Now Dell is telling me it does not recognize the service tag. In order to disqualify a transcription error, I'd like to know if there is any way to find my service tag using the Dell website and my purchase order number or serial number.

Comment: I got the same message when I went to dell.com and entered my service tag. It turned out that dell.com did not recognise my tag, but http://dell.nl/ did.  Might be worth chechking for your country,

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's posisble, without the laptop on hand - you will need access to it. I checked my invoice and it has no mention of the Service tag. If you can connect to it via VNC/RDP then you can find it using (1) wmic

```
C:\Users\Sathya>wmic bios get serialnumber
SerialNumber
CR8XXXX
```

Or (2) via this [link](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/my_systems_info/en/FindTagSysProfLicense?c=us&l=en&s=gen)

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>F2</kbd> before it boots up, and look around in the BIOS screen.  Dells often have their Service Tag displayed there.  If it doesn't match the one on the bottom of the laptop, then you've found the real Service Tag.  If it does match, then that is highly likely it's an issue on Dell's end.

Comment: That would still need to have the laptop on hand... But, it's a good hint to compare the BIOS with the label.

Comment: Hmm... Did you by chance copy down the Express Service Code (ESC) as well? You can compute the Service Tag from that using this page: http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/HT/Dell/DellNumb.htm

Answer (score 1):

Why not email Dell support and tell them your order number and any other pertinent information that you have from your invoice. They should be able to provide you with the service tag as I'm sure they have it tied to your order in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you purchased the laptop as a gift for someone else and would like to take advantage of the upgrade.  First, I am not sure that you would be able to use the upgrade for yourself as it may be tied to Dell systems (a common practice of OEMs)

However, if you are trying to get the upgrade for the person you gave the laptop to, then why not either call them and get the tag number from them or let them know about the upgrade?

Comment: Nope, this is for the laptop owner, I just didn't want to have to involve anyone at Dell or the laptop recipient.